# Ubuntu 17 refuses to boot from PCIe-Disk

Tags: boot, ssd, 17.04

I have an intel pro 750 SSD installed in my PCI-e slot. I was able to install Ubuntu 17 without problem during my initial boot from an Ubuntu CD.

However, when I restarted after the install, I just get a black screen. I could not even get to the BIOS.

Then, I installed a regular SATA SSD, at which point I was able boot from the CD again. I then installed Ubuntu 17 on the SATA SSD, this works without issue, even after restart.

Given the price I paid for the pci ssd (more then all the rest of the computer put together), I would like to use that instead of my sata ssd.

It would be optimal to get that working normally, however if that is not possible, is there a way to use my sata ssd as a bootstrap and tell it to boot from my PCIe SSD?

Comment: That's odd, since the Intel 750 has been supported since kernel `3.19`

Comment: It was working fine in another system using ubuntu 16... that is until the other drive with windows 10 on it decided by itself, encrypted drives are not useful anyway and can be used as scratch space... :/ That's why I built this separate computer

Comment: Do you dual-boot with Windows? Is your computer UEFI? Having used the SSD elsewhere, how did you reinitialize it? GPT partition table?

Comment: I used to dual boot with windows, on a different computer, which worked fine, until windows deleted my ubuntu drive...

Yes it is UEFI. 

I believe so, if that is the default option.

Comment: Yeah, that's a known problem with the Windows 10 Anniversary Update.... it tends to nuke people's non-Windows drives. That's Microsoft for you :D

Comment: You didn't say how you initialized the SSD. Did you lay down a fresh GPT partition table and then build Ubuntu? To direct new comments to my attention, place `@heynnema` at the start of the comment, or I may miss them.

Comment: @AndroidDev yes, and I don't think that MS ever came clean on that major "bug", or tell us if they fixed it :-( Every time I do a can't-opt-out W10 update, I wonder if I'll have any Ubuntu left or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to put your root filesystem on the pcie disk, and boot from another device as long as you can put the other device ahead of the pcie disk in the boot order.  Unfortunately, not all BIOSes will allow that degree of selection on the hard disks.

---

First determine if you can boot the sata disk when the pcie disk is present.  Ensure the sata is before the pcie disk in the boot order if that is possible.  If you can boot sata, and the pcie disk already has an Ubuntu install on it, you should be able to run

```
sudo update-grub
```

and the grub boot menu should now include the pcie disk.

If you cannot boot the sata disk when the pcie disk is present, you may still be able to boot off a USB device which you can put before the HDD in the bootorder.  In that case, boot off a USB, then select the item with the root on the pcie disk.   A regular install to the USB (stick?) should be able to boot, then insert the pcie disk, and boot the USB. Run sudo update-grub to pick up the pcie disk in the USB grub menu, and try a reboot the USB and select the pcie to run.

Unfortunately, installing to a USB is not something the Ubuntu installer does (yet) (bugs 1173457, 1229488,...), and worse, tends to mess up a working Ubuntu on the host. There are other answers on this site for doing a full install to a USB, If you have problems, I can help, but to summarize:

Backup your working hdd boot (the /EFI directory on the EFI partition).  Copy /boot/grub/grub.cfg to a saved copy like /EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg.good so you can restore it if (when) it gets reset to point to the USB (bug). List your working nvram entries with efibootmgr -v, so you can see what works.  Install to the USB in UEFI mode -- EFI partition on the USB should be created, but is left empty. Copy the entire EFI partition off the hdd to the USB.  Fix the USB /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi so it is a copy of grubx64.efi (or shimx64.efi if secure booting, and in that case, also have a copy of grubx64.efi too.)  On the USB, edit the /EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg to use the UUID of the USB root (sdb2?).  Restore the hdd grub.cfg.good to grub.cfg.  Yea, what a mess, just to create a booting UEFI full install USB stick.

---

I had an HP laptop, which hung in grub when I added a second disk to a disk caddy in the optical slot -- this caddy was checked before the original hard disk (regardless of what order I used on the CD/DVD entry), so I could not even have the caddy present and boot off the original disk.  Putting grub onto a USB allowed grub to fully start, and selecting the root fs on the caddy then worked. Maybe that approach would work for you.

Comment: Thanks, can you be a little more specific on how to do this?
I am a bit of a linux newb. Most of my linux experience is redhat on preconfigured servers.

Answer (score 1):

Some PCIe SSDs firmware do not support the ext4 file system, but only NTFS, exfat, hfs +. Use gparted from live CD to check if your SSD supports the ext4 file system.